# RequireJs fail to load scripts randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I've got an HTML template (from themeforest) which has lots of jQuery plugins and a main.js where all of them are instantiated and configured for the template. I'm creating an AngularJS application based on that template, and i'm using RequireJS to load my scripts. In the index.html of the template, I load my require-config.js file. 80% of the times, the app loads just fine, but the other 20%, an error appears like "jQuery is not a function" or "$(...).mmenu is not a function". Here are my files. Can someone figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-lib.js"></script><!-- Jquery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/mapbox.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/build.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquerym.menu/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/Magnific-Popup-master/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jQuery.filer-master/js/jquery.filer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-rating.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/popup/js/classie.js"></script> <!-- Popup -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/popup/js/modalEffects.js"></script> <!-- Popup -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Where the last one is the main.js, where everything is initialized. So now, in my index.html I have this:

```
    <script data-main="require-config" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

My require-confing.js looks like this

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: 'js/jquery-lib',
    jquerymigrate: 'js/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min',
    rating: 'js/bootstrap-rating',
    build: 'js/build.min',
    mapbox: 'js/mapbox',
    leaflet: 'js/leaflet.markercluster',
    chosen: 'lib/chosen/chosen.jquery',
    jqueryui: 'js/jquery-ui',
    slick: 'lib/slick/slick.min',
    jquerymenu: 'lib/jquerym.menu/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all',
    magnific: 'lib/Magnific-Popup-master/jquery.magnific-popup.min',
    fileLoader: 'lib/jQuery.filer-master/js/jquery.filer.min',
    main: 'js/main',
    angular: 'bower_components/angular/angular',
    angularRoute: 'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
    angularMocks: 'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
    angularTranslate: 'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate',
    angularTranslateLoadProvider: 'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files',
    text: 'bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
},
shim: {
    'jquery': {
        'exports': 'jquery'
    },
    'jquerymigrate': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'build': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'mapbox': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'leaflet': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquerymigrate']
    },
    'chosen': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jqueryui': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jqueryui']
    },
    'fileLoader': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'js/bootstrap-rating': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        'exports': 'rating'
    },
    'jquerymenu': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        'exports': 'jquerymenu'
    },
    'magnific': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'main': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jqueryui', 'build', 'mapbox', 'chosen', 'fileLoader', 'rating', 'jquerymenu', 'slick', 'magnific']
    },
    'angular': { 'exports': 'angular' },
    'angularRoute': ['angular'],
    'angularTranslate': ['angular'],
    'angularTranslateLoadProvider': ['angularTranslate'],
    'angularMocks': {
        deps: ['angular'],
        'exports': 'angular.mock'
    }
}
```

And finally my app.js like this

```
    define([
    'angular',
    'angularRoute',
    'angularTranslate',
    'angularTranslateLoadProvider',
    'jquery',
    'build',
    'mapbox',
    'leaflet',
    'chosen',
    'jqueryui',
    'rating',
    'slick',
    'jquerymenu',
    'fileLoader',
    'main',
    'view1/view1',
    'view2/view2'
], function (angular, angularRoute, view1, view2, angularTranslate, angularTranslateLoadProvider) {
    // Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
    return angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'myApp.view1',
        'myApp.view2'
    ]).config(['$routeProvider', '$translateProvider', function ($routeProvider, $translateProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/menu', {
            resolve: {
                "prevent": function () {
                    window.location.href = window.lastPath;
                }
            }
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'translations/',
            suffix: '.json'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('es');
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Any reason why you are shimming `jQuery`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak i'm new to requierjs. I try to fix it by watching ither questions and arrived to that. Can't really say

Comment: Okay, you only shim those libraries which are not AMD compliant. jQuery is AMD compliant, so you may remove the shim for jQuery.

Comment: @SandeepNayak i've removed 'jquery': {
        'exports': 'jquery'
    } from the shim but is still happening. It´s like main is executing before all the other libraries are loaded

Comment: You are doing a mistake. You need to only refer to `main.js` in your HTML. EVerything else needs to be defined in the main.js. So you need to remove all other script tags and keep only main.js in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem according to me

Your order in `define` should match the arguments in the `function`.

For example,

```
define(['module1', 'module2',......, 'moduleK'], function(module1, module2,...., moduleK){

});
```

The order of arguments in your callback should match the order in which you are requireing the modules as dependencies in your `define`

Hence, your code should look something like this;

```
 define([
    'angular',
    'angularRoute',
    'angularTranslate',
    'angularTranslateLoadProvider',
    'jquery',
    'build',
    'mapbox',
    'leaflet',
    'chosen',
    'jqueryui',
    'rating',
    'slick',
    'jquerymenu',
    'fileLoader',
    'main',
    'view1/view1',
    'view2/view2'
], function (angular, angularRoute, angularTranslate, angularTranslateLoadProvider, $, build, mapbox, leaflet, chosen, jqueryui, rating, slick, jquerymenu, fileloader, main, view1, view2) {
.....
```

Comment: no...i've changed my function declaration in my app.js but the issue is still happening. I guess the issue is the loading time of the scripts. In the 80% of the cases, jQuery and the other libraries are loading before main.js, as declared in the shim. But when main.js runs before jQuery or jqmenu or other, it throws the exception